# recorrer un arbol binario en recorrido postorden sin usar recursividad ; error de compilacion

Tags: c++, stack

estructura de nodos

```
template<class T>
struct Nodo {

     public:
        T elemento;
        Nodo<T> *HIzq;
        Nodo<T> *HDer;
    };
```

la funcion siguiente debe de imprimir en pantalla todos los nodos del arbol en postorden pero devuelve el codigo de error  -1073741819 (0xC0000005) cuando entra en el primer if dentro del while mis preguntas son 2 : cual puede ser el error? y la logica de la funcion es correcta?

```
void ArbolBin<T>::listarPostOrden(){
    stack<Nodo<T> *> pila, anterior;
    pila.push(this->raiz);
    cout << '\n';
    while(!pila.empty()){
        cout << pila.top()->elemento << '|';
        if(pila.top()->HIzq != nullptr && pila.top()->HIzq != anterior.top()){
            pila.push(pila.top()->HIzq);
        }
        else if(pila.top()->HDer != nullptr && pila.top()->HDer != anterior.top()){
            pila.push(pila.top()->HDer);
        }
        else{
            anterior.push(pila.top());
            pila.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

explicacion de la funcion: lo primero que hago es crear 2 pilas contenedoras de nodos, le inserto el nodo raiz del arbol a la primera pila luego mientras que esta pila no este vacia se repite el siguiente procedimiento:
imprime el elemento del nodo del tope de la pila, despues si el hijo izquierod del nodo no es un puntero nulo y es diferente al tope de la pila "anterior" mete el nodo "hijo izquierdo"  a la pila, el procedimiento con el hijo derecho es analogo al del hijo izquiero. luego si no ocurre ninguna de las anteriores condiciones mete el tope de la pila a la pila "anterior" y elimina el tope de la pila

Comment: Ayúdanos a que te ayudemos publicando un [ejemplo minimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Para esta clase de problemas necesitamos correrlo en nuestras computadoras para ver que es lo que esta pasando. Un código que pueda simplemente copiar, pegar en mi maquina, y ver el error del que estas hablando.